# Talend parallel Jobs

Tags: talend

I start 7 Talend parallel Jobs. Sometimes ALL Jobs started without mistake! Sometimes 4 or 5 Jobs started successfully and for the rest became the mistakes:
"Error by calling Job"
or 
"Unable to create new native thread"

Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks

Comment: This is impossible to answer without further information. Please [edit] your question and add information about the size and complexity of the jobs, the general runtime of the jobs, the created amount of threads, the scheduling information how often and when the jobs start and why you need to start them parallel.

Comment: please give a screen shot of your job...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. There is more than one possibilities.

[Talend Expert](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-job-parallelization-reference.html) or [Talend by example](https://talendexpert.com/job-parallelization-talend-multi-threading-talend/)

Comment: Thank  you Théo. an additional info: I have a different Talend Job and NOT a Job with different subjob!!!

Comment: That is not a problem. You can make a job with multiple job inside if you use the component tRunjob